# Scikit's Support Vector Regression - problem emulating code from their website

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, svm

as the title suggests I'm attempting to emulate a couple regression functions from Scikit Learns website (with my own data) and am having some problems plotting my results.

The stock code: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_regression.html

My problem: My figure plots multiple regression lines (see figures below).

```
In:  #select features
     feature_cols = ['avg_r']

     #x def
     X= df_s[feature_cols]
     X= df_s[['avg_r']]
     print("X type", type(X))
     print("X shape", X.shape)

     #y def
     y = df_s['sales']
     y = df_s.sales
     print("y type", type(y))
     print("y shape",y.shape)
```

```
Out: X type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
     X shape (1105, 1)
     y type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
     y shape (1105,)
```

```
In: X.head()
```

```
Out:     avg_r
0   470.500000
1   717.750000
2   603.416667
3   566.416667
4   778.333333
```

```
In: y.head()
```

```
Out: 0    2412
     1    1308
     2    2037
     3    2052
     4    1553
     Name: sales, dtype: int64
```

```
In: #split data into training and test subsets
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y)

    print("X_train", X_train.shape)
    print("X_test", X_test.shape)
    print("y_train", y_train.shape)
    print("y_train", y_test.shape)
```

```
Out: X_train (828, 1)
     X_test (277, 1)
     y_train (828,)
     y_train (277,)
```

```
In: #fit regression models

    svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e4, gamma=0.0025)
    svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
    #svr_poly = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree=2)

    y_rbf = svr_rbf.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
    y_lin = svr_lin.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
    #y_poly = svr_poly.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
```

```
Out: blank
```

```
In: # Look at the results
    lw = 2
    plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, color='darkorange', label='sales')
    plt.plot(X_test, y_rbf, color='navy', lw=lw, label='RBF model')
    #plt.plot(X_test, y_lin, color='c', lw=lw, label='Linear model')
    #plt.plot(X_test.avg_r, y_poly, color='cornflowerblue', lw=lw, 
    label='Polynomial model')
    plt.xlabel('rank')
    plt.ylabel('sales')
    plt.title('Support Vector Regression')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

```
Out:
```

[image]

If I instead plot the regressions as a scatters I get this:

```
In: # Look at the results
    lw = 2
    plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, color='darkorange', label='sales')
    plt.scatter(X_test, y_rbf, color='navy', lw=lw, label='RBF model')
    #plt.plot(X_test, y_lin, color='c', lw=lw, label='Linear model')
    #plt.plot(X_test.avg_r, y_poly, color='cornflowerblue', lw=lw, 
    label='Polynomial model')
    plt.xlabel('rank')
    plt.ylabel('sales')
    plt.title('Support Vector Regression')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

```
Out:
```

[image]

Comment: @desertnaut fixed.

Comment: downvote & close vote retracted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not produce "multiple regression lines".

The `plt.plot(X,y)` method plots lines between each point of your data *in the order you passed them*. Here is an example that illustrates what is going on:

```
X = np.array([1,2,4,3])
y = np.array([0,0.5,2,1.5])

plt.plot(X,y)
```

You will get

[image: unsorted plot]

However if you do this

```
X1 = X[np.argsort(X)]
y1 = y[np.argsort(X)]

plt.plot(X1,y1)
```

You will this time get

[image: sorted plot]

So all you need to do is to do the same correction to your code:

```
X_test, y_rbf = X_test[np.argsort(X_test)], y_rbf[np.argsort(X_test)]
```